# Javascript get responseText from object

Tags: javascript, response, responsetext

I have this response when I call URL:

[image]

Now I want to get `responseText.message`

but I dont know how...

I try:

```
Object.responseText.message
```

and

```
 Data.responseText.message
```

and

```
data.message
```

but I get Undefined

How to get reponseText?

Comment: That error is local to your code, so you most probably cannot access it from the console (unless it is defined as a global variable.

Comment: Pleas post the complete code which makes the ajax request.

Comment: You won't be able to use the responseText string as an object, but you'll see that a responseJSON object that has been parsed for you.